# Active Directory User Photos in Sharepoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We currently have SPF2010 setup which uses AD to authenticate users.
This method, though, does not pull user data (Department, Phone etc.) from AD due to the fact that there is no User Profile Service for Sharepoint Foundation.

We would like to be able to pull elements like user photos from AD so they display in sharepoint's user profile.

Does anyone know of a workaround that would allow this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need some type of code to accomplish this.  You can write the sync yourself or I think I've seen a few projects on the interwebs that do this for SharePoint Foundation (they might have been for WSS 3.0 though, I don't remember).

You also might be able to do this through forefront identity manager.

In my mind I would make a timer job that loops through all of the site collections, loops through all of the users in the userinformationlist and get's their info from AD (caches it for the duration of the running job) then updates that user's information in the userinformationlist (maybe upload a picture, set the url, etc) from the values returned in AD.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on user logon, rather than a timer job?